# Are there methods to convert a delay differential equation (DDE) into a (second-order) ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of three non-linear differential equations of which one has a delay. Is it possible to convert such a system into (second-order) ODEs?

Answer (score 11):

Usually this is not possible. This can be seen already for scalar first order delay equations such as $x'(t)= x(t-1)$.

Any complex valued function $x(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ is a solution if $\lambda$ satisfies the characteristic equation
$$
\lambda = e^{-\lambda} \, .
$$
There are infinitely many complex solutions of this equation, given by
$$
0.567143,\; -1.53391\pm 4.37519 i,\; -2.40159\pm10.7763 i,\; -2.85358\pm17.1135
   i,\;  \dots
$$
That is not possible for any constant coefficient differential equation of any order, for which the characteristic equation only has finitely many solutions.

The situation does not improve for nonlinear equations.